# Dynamics Nav C/AL naming conventions

Tags: naming-conventions, microsoft-dynamics

I am facing certain C/AL tasks those days and as I am used to code in c#, C/AL seems a bit "different" in several aspects.
In particular I am wondering, why it is recommed to use variable names starting with uppercase letters. 
From my point of view it would be a benefit in terms of readability to use camelcase notation for variables.
Is there any reason, why it is recommed that way by Microsoft?

Answer (score 1):

I do not think there is a specific reason why the Pascal Case (first letter always uppercase) is used. That being said it is more of a guideline for all developers so that the code is uniform across all products. The general idea is that if you merge code from two different sources (e.g. two different developers) the end result would appear as if the code was from a single source.

Some companies have their own internal rules how code should be formatted. I prefer the use of the naming conventions specified by Microsoft because:

- it makes my code consistent with the Navision standard code (objects in the range 1..49999),
- it makes my code consistent with my coworkers (our company policy is to use the Microsoft naming conventions).

The [MSDN Naming Conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee414213(v=nav.90).aspx) page states:

> "Precise and consistent terminology helps the end user work with the application. Rules for naming and abbreviating objects also help developers to understand the CRONUS International Ltd. demonstration database and develop new features faster."

Pascal Case should be used for general code consistency and overall uniformity but is not necessary or required. I would advise you to consult your company policy on Naming Conventions and follow those or if you are starting fresh to follow the Microsoft naming guidelines.